# how to configure phpmyadmin after "sudo yum install phpMyAdmin" ? on amazon ec2 linux ami

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin

after I install phpmyadmin by "sudo yum install phpMyAdmin", it installed successfully.

However, when I type http://example.com/phpmyadmin always get "The requested URL /phpmyadmin was not found on this server."

So my question is how to configure phpmyadmin after install it, I searched online for lots post and none of them solves my problem so far, any suggestions? (I restarted apache after install phpmyadmin and it didnt work)

Background: using amazon ec2 linux ami, php/apache/mysql up and running.
(and where can I find apache installed directory and phpmyadmin configure file? 
I tried /etc/apache, but apache is not there)

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: No idea about your specific issue, but `find / -name phpMyAdmin 2>/dev/null` is always a half-decent first step.

Comment: eventually I solved the problem via this tutorial: 
https://gist.github.com/aronwoost/1105007